# TypeError: 'Frame' object is not callable error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to write a code that will first create a dataframe from an excel document, create a tkinter window and a frame inside of the window that is essentially a megawidget. The for loop at the bottom is meant to create new instances of the megawidget.

```
import pandas
from tkinter import *
#assigns a dataframe variable
summer17=pandas.read_excel("summer17.xlsx","list")

window=Tk()#Start of the main window
row_widget = Frame(window)#Creates a frame or "megawidget"
row_widget.grid()
#Variaous variables for widget parameters
tw_height = 1.5
tw_width1 = 30
tw_width2 = 5
brew_row = 14
#Text blocks for megawidget
t1=Text(row_widget,height=tw_height,width=tw_width1)
t1.grid(row=0,column=0)
t1.insert(END,summer17.iloc[brew_row,0])

t2=Text(row_widget,height=tw_height,width=tw_width1)
t2.grid(row=0,column=1)
t2.insert(END,summer17.iloc[brew_row,1])

t3=Text(row_widget,height=tw_height,width=tw_width2)
t3.grid(row=0,column=2)
t3.insert(END,summer17.iloc[brew_row,2])

t4=Text(row_widget,height=tw_height,width=tw_width2)
t4.grid(row=0,column=3)
t4.insert(END,summer17.iloc[brew_row,3])

t5=Text(row_widget,height=tw_height,width=tw_width2)
t5.grid(row=0,column=4)
t5.insert(END,summer17.iloc[brew_row,4])

t6=Text(row_widget,height=tw_height,width=tw_width2)
t6.grid(row=0,column=5)
t6.insert(END,summer17.iloc[brew_row,5])
#for loop to create new instances of the megawidget
for i in range(len(summer17.index)):
    row = row_widget(Frame)
    row.grid(row=i,column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

and after all of that, I get this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dataframe_v1.py", line 40, in 
    row = row_widget(Frame)
TypeError: 'Frame' object is not callable

Comment: You have simply created a single instance of your `row_widget`: you have not implemented any function or class that would allow you to create more of them, and widgets have no built-in way to duplicate themselves.

Comment: isn't that what the row.grid(row=i,column=0) line is supposed to do? Also, what do you mean by duplicate? They all (in theory) should be unique lines that effectively recreate a data frame, or spreadsheet, that should like basically identical to the Excel spreadsheet the data is pulled from.

Comment: since you've already defined `row_widget = Frame(window)`, wouldn't you only need `row = row_widget`?

Comment: Yup, that's the problem. I swear it is the simplest things sometimes. Now that the error is gone I have to figure out how to make the for loop create a new widget every time it iterates. But, that is a problem for another question thread.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments above, the solution this question is to remove the `(Frame)` from the for loop. It should now look like

```
for i in range(len(summer17.index)):
    row = row_widget
    row.grid(row=i,column=0)
```